# Can't run For loop containg NDSolve and Plot

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, warning-messages

I easily can solve a delayed differential equation and plot it using the following commands:

```
c = 1; r = 1;
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == -c x[t - r], x[t /; t <= 0] == 1}, x, {t, -1, 5}];
Plot[Evaluate[{x[t]} /. sol], {t, -1, 10}]
```

[image]

I would let to solve and plot the results for different r. Using the following code

```
c = 1; \[Epsilon] = 0.0001;
rset = {0, 0 + \[Epsilon], 1/E, 1/E + \[Epsilon], Pi/2, 
   Pi/2 + \[Epsilon]};

For[i = 0, i <= Length[rset], i++,
 r = rset[[i]];
 sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == -c x[t - r], x[t /; t <= 0] == 1}, 
   x, {t, -1, 5}];
 Plot[Evaluate[{x[t]} /. sol], {t, -1, 10}];]
```

Which produces many errors.
[image]
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is the definition of `crset` inside `Length` inside the `For` loop? Should that be `rset`?

Comment: Yes it should be I would correct it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Table[
 Plot[
   Evaluate@NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == -c x[t - r], x[t /; t <= 0] == 1}, x[t], {t, -1, 5}],
   {t, -1, 10}],
 {r, rset}
]
```

Note the use of `NDSolveValue`, which directly outputs `x[t]` rather than a replacement rule.

A `For` loop doesn't output anything, so you would need to use `Print`. Better to use `Table` or `Do`.

---

As far as why your code didn't work: it's because lists in *Mathematica* are indexed starting with 1, not zero. You implicitly tried to do

```
r = rset[[0]]
```

which evaluates to the `Head` of the expression `rset`, which is `List` and not a number. So `NDSolve` didn't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [`ParametricNDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve)/[`ParametricNDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue)? For instance

```
With[{c=1},
    sol=ParametricNDSolveValue[{x'[t]==-c x[t-r],x[t/;t<=0]==1},x,{t,-1,5},r]
]
```

> ParametricFunction[ <> ]

Then, you can plot `sol`, e.g.:

```
Plot[Evaluate[sol[Pi/2][t]], {t, -1, 5}]
```

[image]

Or, for your `rset`:

```
Plot[Evaluate[sol[#][t]], {t, -1, 5}] & /@ rset
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I did not know that this function even existed.